# How do I get ruby gems to include all dependencies of a gem, even ones in BETA?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

Ruby gems only seems to include non-beta dependencies. eg. try:

```
gem install ripple --include-dependencies
```

: and you get the message:

```
ERROR:  Error installing ripple:
    ripple requires activesupport (~> 3.0.0.beta, runtime)
```

Update:
I found that this isn't possible in ruby gems. This however finally worked. Thanks @levi:

```
gem update --system
gem install tzinfo builder memcache-client rack rack-test rack-mount erubis mail text-format thor bundler i18n
gem install rails --pre
gem install ripple
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yup, rubygems can't resolve prerelease gems.

The workaround (resolving the dependencies by hand) should look like this:

`gem install tzinfo builder memcache-client rack rack-test rack-mount erubis mail text-format thor bundler i18n`

`gem install rails --pre`

`gem install ripple`

Comment: Running the first part gave:

ERROR:  Error installing bundler:
 bundler requires RubyGems version >= 1.3.6

So you have to update rubygems first

Comment: Wrong. This bug was fixed in the current version of RubyGems.

Answer (score 5):

Upgrade your RubyGems version, this is fixed as of RubyGems 1.3.6.

Answer (score 0):

It's a limitation of the current rubygems. Install the beta version of activesupport manually.

Comment: This is wrong. This bug was specifically fixed in the current version of RubyGems.

Comment: Oh; sweet! I had not realized RubyGems had gone up a rev.